# Add tuples into a list without unpack the tuple

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

In Python, I have some tuples like b, and I want to add them into an empty list without unpack them. Here, I simplify b so that it repeats itself, in reality, the values in b would be different, so b would be b1, b2, b3...

```
b = ({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'y')
bb = [b, b, b]
print(len(bb))
print(len(bb[0]))
bb
```

This gives

```
3 2 Out[204]: [({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'y'),  ({'a': 1, 'b': 1,'c': 1}, 'y'),  ({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'y')]
```

which is what I want. But since I am now doing in a loop, I can not write bb = [b, b, b]. The syntax I came up with will make hiarachy that I do not want.

```
bb = ()
b = ({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'y')
bb = [bb, b] 
# in reality I loop bb with 3 times in for loop
bb = [bb, b]
bb = [bb, b]
print(len(bb))
print(len(bb[0]))
bb
```

This gives

```
[[[(), ({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'y')], ({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1},'y')],  ({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'y')]
```

and is not want I wanted. How can I loop and reach the first outcome?

Comment: Be wary with what `[b, b, b]` does - it creates reference copies of the _dictionary_ in each tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Just use list comprehension:

```
b = ({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'y')
bb = [b for i in range(3)]
```

Output:

```
[({'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, 'y'), ({'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, 'y'), ({'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, 'y')]
```

Comment: Thank you, but in reality, my b(s) will be different in value each time... it could be ({'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'y'), ({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}, 'y')... so the syntax you provided wont work...

Comment: Your list comprehension is a verbose way to write `bb = [b]*3` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Start with a list and use `append`:

```
bb = []
b = ({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'y')
for _ in range(3):
    bb.append(b)
```